# Exception caught by widgets library NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, ios, api, flutter, dart

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

The relevant error-causing widget was:
MaterialApp file:///C:/Users/Ahmed/AndroidStudioProjects/weather_app/lib/main.dart:9:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

## 0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)

## 1      _LocationScreenState.UpdateUI. (package:weatherapp/screens/location_screen.dart:27:38)

## 2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1148:30)

## 3      _LocationScreenState.UpdateUI (package:weatherapp/screens/location_screen.dart:26:5)

## 4      _LocationScreenState.initState (package:weatherapp/screens/location_screen.dart:23:1)

At #1

```
`void UpdateUI(dynamic weatherdata){
    setState(() {
    double temp = weatherdata['main']['temp'];
    temperature  = temp.toInt();
    var condition = weatherdata['weather'][0]['id'];
    weatherIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);
    weatherDescription = weather.getMessage(temperature);
    cityname  = weatherdata['name'];
    });
  }`
```

At #4

````
```
   void initState() {
    super.initState();
UpdateUI(widget.locationWeather);
  }
```
````

I was trying to take data from this API link below
https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=50228b366a46bef0c96ee6e6cecd4b6a

Comment: Check and print weatherdata

Comment: yes it's fine now there was a problem in my API the conversion into unit metrics was done inappropriately thanks by the way.